# Create month dummies based on start and end date (in R or Stata)

Tags: r, stata

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5), `start month` = c(1, 
4, 5, 8, 12, 11, 10, 3, 5, 6, 2, 1), `start year` = c(1999, 2018, 
2017, 2019, 1980, 2019, 2016, 2020, 2022, 2019, 2015, 2016), 
    `end month` = c(4, 2, 0, 12, 0, 12, 5, 0, 0, 11, 5, 9), `end year` = c(2020, 
    2019, 0, 2022, 0, 2019, 2017, 0, 0, 2020, 2019, 2017)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))

# A tibble: 12 × 5
      id `start month` `start year` `end month` `end year`
   <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     1             1         1999           4       2020
 2     1             4         2018           2       2019
 3     2             5         2017           0          0
 4     2             8         2019          12       2022
 5     2            12         1980           0          0
 6     2            11         2019          12       2019
 7     3            10         2016           5       2017
 8     4             3         2020           0          0
 9     4             5         2022           0          0
10     4             6         2019          11       2020
11     4             2         2015           5       2019
12     5             1         2016           9       2017
```

For each id, I have the start and end date of a person's relationship with a bank.

I want to define dummies (equal to 1 if the relationship exists and 0 otherwise) for each month from July 2016 to December 2019. So I would like to have thirty dummies for each row.
I would like the column names to be 201607, 201608, 201609, [...], 201911, 201912.

If both "end month" and "end year" are 0, the relationship exists until today (hence, also to the end of my period of interest).

Stata example:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input byte(id startmonth) int startyear byte endmonth int endyear
1  1 1999  4 2020
1  4 2018  2 2019
2  5 2017  0    0
2  8 2019 12 2022
2 12 1980  0    0
2 11 2019 12 2019
3 10 2016  5 2017
4  3 2020  0    0
4  5 2022  0    0
4  6 2019 11 2020
4  2 2015  5 2019
5  1 2016  9 2017
end
```

Comment: This is the latest in a series of R or Stata questions and typically you don't show any attempt at code in either language. As you've hitherto got plenty of R solutions and accepted one of them, I can only infer that  your preference is for R -- which is fine, but please don't waste the time of Stata people asking for a solution you won't use,

Comment: FWIW, good Stata practice would be to create a monthly date variable using something like `ym(year, month)` -- as already mentioned in earlier threads.

Answer (score 1):

In `R`, try

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(`end month` = case_match(`end month`, 0 ~ month(today()), 
    .default =  `end month`),
    `end year` = case_match(`end year`, 0 ~ year(today()),
    .default =  `end year`)) %>% 
   transmute(rn = row_number(), id, 
   dates = map2(as.Date(ISOdate(`start year`, `start month`, 1)), 
     as.Date(ISOdate(`end year`, `end month`, 1)),
      ~seq(.x, .y, by = '1 month') %>% 
      subset(between(., ymd('2016-06-01'), ymd('2020-01-01'))) %>% 
        format('%Y%m'))) %>%
    unnest(dates) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = dates, values_from = dates,
       values_fn = length, values_fill = 0) %>%
   select(-rn)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 45
      id `201606` `201607` `201608` `201609` `201610` `201611` `201612` 20170…¹ 20170…² 20170…³ 20170…⁴ 20170…⁵ 20170…⁶ 20170…⁷ 20170…⁸ 20170…⁹ 20171…˟
   <dbl>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
 1     1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
 2     1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 3     2        0        0        0        0        0        0        0       0       0       0       0       1       1       1       1       1       1
 4     2        0        0        0        0        0        0        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 5     2        1        1        1        1        1        1        1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
 6     2        0        0        0        0        0        0        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 7     3        0        0        0        0        1        1        1       1       1       1       1       1       0       0       0       0       0
 8     4        0        0        0        0        0        0        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
 9     4        1        1        1        1        1        1        1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
10     5        1        1        1        1        1        1        1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       0
# … with 27 more variables: `201711` <int>, `201712` <int>, `201801` <int>, `201802` <int>, `201803` <int>, `201804` <int>, `201805` <int>,
#   `201806` <int>, `201807` <int>, `201808` <int>, `201809` <int>, `201810` <int>, `201811` <int>, `201812` <int>, `201901` <int>, `201902` <int>,
#   `201903` <int>, `201904` <int>, `201905` <int>, `201906` <int>, `201907` <int>, `201908` <int>, `201909` <int>, `201910` <int>, `201911` <int>,
#   `201912` <int>, `202001` <int>, and abbreviated variable names ¹​`201701`, ²​`201702`, ³​`201703`, ⁴​`201704`, ⁵​`201705`, ⁶​`201706`, ⁷​`201707`,
#   ⁸​`201708`, ⁹​`201709`, ˟​`201710`
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How can I adapt for dplyr <= 1.1.0?

Comment: @Rnovice just modify the `case_match` to `case_when`

Answer (score 0):

Another R approach. (Since you mentioned thirty dummy variables, the end column is `201812` not `201912`.)

```r
  suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
  suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(lubridate))
  library(purrr)
  df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5),
               `start month` = c(1, 4, 5, 8, 12, 11, 10, 3, 5, 6, 2, 1),
               `start year` = c(1999, 2018,2017, 2019, 1980, 2019, 2016,
                                2020, 2022, 2019, 2015, 2016), 
               `end month` = c(4, 2, 0, 12, 0, 12, 5, 0, 0, 11, 5, 9),
               `end year` = c(2020, 2019, 0, 2022, 0, 2019, 2017, 0, 0, 2020,
                              2019, 2017)),
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
  d <- ymd("2016-07-01") + months(0:29)
  
  create_dummies <- function(start, end, d) {
    setNames(as.numeric(d >= start & d <= end), paste0(substr(d, 1, 4),
                                                       substr(d, 6, 7)))
    }
  
  dummies <- df |> mutate(`end year` = ifelse(`end year` == 0, year(today()),
                                              `end year`),
             `end month` = ifelse(`end month` == 0, month(today()),
                                  `end month`),
             start = ymd(paste(`start year`, `start month`, "01")),
             end = ymd(paste(`end year`, `end month`, "01")))

bind_cols(df, map2(dummies$start, dummies$end, create_dummies, d) |>
            map_df(~.x))

#> # A tibble: 12 × 35
#>       id start…¹ start…² end m…³ end y…⁴ 20160…⁵ 20160…⁶ 20160…⁷ 20161…⁸ 20161…⁹
#>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1     1       1    1999       4    2020       1       1       1       1       1
#>  2     1       4    2018       2    2019       0       0       0       0       0
#>  3     2       5    2017       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
#>  4     2       8    2019      12    2022       0       0       0       0       0
#>  5     2      12    1980       0       0       1       1       1       1       1
#>  6     2      11    2019      12    2019       0       0       0       0       0
#>  7     3      10    2016       5    2017       0       0       0       1       1
#>  8     4       3    2020       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
#>  9     4       5    2022       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
#> 10     4       6    2019      11    2020       0       0       0       0       0
#> 11     4       2    2015       5    2019       1       1       1       1       1
#> 12     5       1    2016       9    2017       1       1       1       1       1
#> # … with 25 more variables: `201612` <dbl>, `201701` <dbl>, `201702` <dbl>,
#> #   `201703` <dbl>, `201704` <dbl>, `201705` <dbl>, `201706` <dbl>,
#> #   `201707` <dbl>, `201708` <dbl>, `201709` <dbl>, `201710` <dbl>,
#> #   `201711` <dbl>, `201712` <dbl>, `201801` <dbl>, `201802` <dbl>,
#> #   `201803` <dbl>, `201804` <dbl>, `201805` <dbl>, `201806` <dbl>,
#> #   `201807` <dbl>, `201808` <dbl>, `201809` <dbl>, `201810` <dbl>,
#> #   `201811` <dbl>, `201812` <dbl>, and abbreviated variable names …
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>